# Is there an OR clause in LINQ?

Tags: linq

I am trying to query an XML document for the specific records that I need.  I know that the line containing the "or where" case below is incorrect, but I'm hoping it will illustrate what I am trying to accomplish.  Can you do a conditional where clause on two seperate properties?

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load("CardData.xml");
SearchList.ItemsSource = from x in xd.Descendants("card")
                         where x.Element("title").Value.ToUpper().Contains(searchterm.ToUpper())
                         or where x.Element("id").Value.Contains(searchterm)
                         select new Card
                         {
                             Title = x.Element("title").Value
                         };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - simply use the boolean or || and combine your conditions into one `Where` clause:

```
where x.Element("title").Value.ToUpper().Contains(searchterm.ToUpper()) || 
      x.Element("id").Value.Contains(searchterm)
```

Also note just as a minor optimization, I would pre-compute some of the operations you currently have in your Where clause so they are not performed on every item in the list - probably doesn't matter but it might when you have a lot of elements (and is just a good habit to get into in my opinion):

```
string searchTermUpperCase = searchterm.ToUpper();
SearchList.ItemsSource = from x in xd.Descendants("card")
                         where x.Element("title").Value.ToUpper().Contains(searchTermUpperCase)
                         or where x.Element("id").Value.Contains(searchterm)
                         ..
```